# Piping Remote files in Node JS looking for alternative ways

Tags: node.js, express, axios, node-streams, node-fetch

I was using a `request` module and that is deprecated now. It was useful to pipe the remote files without storing in server. So looking for an alternative solution of the same function with Node-fetch, GOT, Axios etc..

```
import request from 'request';

    (req, res) { 
       return request(`http://files.com/image.jpg`)
            .on('error', (err) => {
              log.error('error fetching img url: %O', err);
              res.status(500).end('error serving this file');
            })
            .on('response', (urlRes) => {
              if (urlRes.statusCode === 304) return;
              urlRes.headers['content-disposition'] = `inline;filename="${slug}"`;
            })
            .pipe(res);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this way with `node-fetch` module, it works. But it doesn't pipe the response headers as like in `request` module. So we need to do set the required headers manually.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
(req, res) {
 fetch('http://files.com/image.jpg').then((response) => {
      res.set({
        'content-length': response.headers.get('content-length'),
        'content-disposition': `inline;filename="${slug}"`,        
        'content-type': response.headers.get('content-type'),        
      })
      response.body.pipe(res);
      response.body.on('error', () => {}) // To handle failure
    });
}
```